# QueryException shows error with the query in it

Tags: php, exception, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm using doctrine and its the best thing i have ever seen, but I have a little problem with it. I'm making a search for my webapplication and i need an query for that, because with the find function you cant search.

Well I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Because the QueryException shows an error even when its the simplest query. Here is some code of mine:

```
$this->_em->createQuery('SELECT * FROM parcel u WHERE u.parcel_id = "1"')
                     ->getResult();
```

I just want to get an parcel (just a test). And this is what i get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message 'SELECT * FROM parcel u WHERE u.parcel_id = "1"'
```

That's not an easy error. I dont know what i'm doing wrong.
Maybe my bootstrap is something missing?

I have doctrine with Codeigniter, maybe thats the deal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of selecting everything with `*` as in SQL you need to select the entire object with Doctrine.

So instead of `*` use `u`.
Total:

```
$this->_em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM Parcel u WHERE u.parcel_id = "1"')
    ->getResult();
```

Also the data you are querying for should be an object. Classes usualy are written with first letter uppercase.